# Ahn'Morpork: Placed to one side

Tags: discworld-ankh-morpork

On some cards I've read "Place to one side" and I couldn't understand does that mean that it is removed? If said for a building does it mean that it is destroyed or has a different meaning? I couldn't find that in the rules.

The card that baffled me was Bloody Stupid Johnson: "Roll the die. If the City Area card of the same value is in play then that card is placed to one side. The owner of the card must also remove one of his minions from the same area as the card."

How is this played out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bloody Stupid Johnson works like this: 
You roll for a random city area. When you roll an area that contains a building, the owner of that building has to put the corresponding area card away. The card says "to one side" but the important thing here is that the area card is removed from play. The building is still there, it still counts as a building for all intents and purposes (win conditions, for instance), but the owner can no longer use the power on the area card.

[According to Martin Wallace](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/700410/bloody-stupid-johnson-combo-fire-question), the designer of the game, the card is back in the game if the bulding gets destroyed and subsequently rebuilt (by the same player or another).